# External monitor through thunderbolt eGPU not recognized by Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, gpu, external-monitor

I just bought a Razer Core X Chroma in combination with a Gigabyte RTX 3070. These are used in combination with a HP Zbook studio which supports thunderbolt 3. I use a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as my operating system.

To configure the eGPU I used the following tutorial: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-machine-learning-on-a-linux-laptop-with-an-external-gpu/

I also searched the internet for solutions which caused me to perform the following actions

- I set the ‘Thunderbolt Security Level’ to ‘PCIe and DisplayPort - No Security’ in the bios.
- In the xorg.conf file I also added ‘Option “AllowExternalGpus” “True”’ to the devices sections of the Geforce RTX 3070.
- I use lightdm as my display manager, instead of gdm3
- I updated the drivers to nvidia-driver-460

Everything seems to work fine since the eGPU is recognized by nvidia-smi:
[Screenshot of nvidia-smi command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m7z8.png)

Also the external displays which are attached with hdmi to the eGPU are recognized by NVIDIA X Server Settings.

The problem is that the external displays are showing my cursor (as a weird cross), but are not recognized as displays in the Ubuntu settings and do not show any windows. Therefore I am not able to use the external monitors.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following GitHub: https://github.com/hertg/egpu-switcher

Running this solved the problem for me.